# Variadic functions, functors, and multiple definitions

Tags: c++

I was implementing a sum method, which would allow you to write: `sum(1, 3.5, 100, 43.9)` and retrieve a sum finally that reflects the addition of all the numbers. Now there are plenty of ways one can implement something like this obviously.

```
template<typename... Args>
auto sum(Args... args)
{
  return (args + ...);
}
```

And then there is this definition:

```
template<typename T>
auto sum(T v){ return v; }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto sum(T v, Args&&... args)
{
    return v + sum(args...);
}
```

**N.B.** Now in both cases, I get the exact same result, e.g., `sum(3, 10, 5.8);` gives `18.8` in both cases. Providing only one number gives the same number back.

**Questions:**

- Any difference here from a compiler standpoint (think: *optimization*)?
- What is the real reason behind having two implementations vs. only one single which does the exact same thing?

I also read about the `<functional>` header, which provides things like `std::plus`, `std::minus`, `std::multiplies`, and `std::divides`.

Comment: Implementation dependent. Be specific about the compiler.

Comment: @Jason, **Hi!**, what do you mean by that statement?

Comment: Usually it should not matter. If you have C++17 or higher available, then choose option `1`, if not then you can always use `2`.

Comment: @Jason, I see. I am working under `C++ 20`.

Comment: Then option `1` is the clear(and better) choice for the given example.

Comment: btw in both cases its templates that get instantiated to N different functions.

Comment: I would also recommend looking at the generated code using [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/b46b8db3). That should clear your doubts.

Comment: @Jason, As I suspected. That the first one is more preferred here. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: Now where's the functor mentioned in the question's title? You also write you were "implementing a [...] method" when it's actually a function template. Nitpicking? Yes. These words have a very specific meaning and you should learn to use them correctly.

Comment: @Friedrich, **COOL** dude. You are doing great!

Comment: @AlixBlaine would you go to a doctor who tells you it's your stomach that pumps blood through your body? Would you have your car repaired at a shop where they confuse steering with road wheels? I'm not expecting gratitude but please try to understand that I wrote what I wrote to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the real reason behind having two implementations vs. only one
> single which does the exact same thing?

I will attempt to answer this by showing how it was before C++17 and how C++17's `compile-time if` can bake the base case into the main function.

---

In C++14 there was no fold expressions and no `if constexpr`, and therefore
the following example:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto sum(T v, Args&&... args)
{
    return v + sum(args...);
}
```

if instantiating it with:

```
sum(1, 3.14);
```

The compiler will complain that it had a problem at *instantiation time*
of the template where `T = double; Args = {}]`. In other words, you don't have a
function to end the recursion.

The solution then was to provide a second function template that ends the recursion.

---

C++17 came along and provided `if constexpr`, and this solves the "problem"
mentioned above and provides us a shortcut:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto sum(T v, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0)
        return v;
    else
        return v + sum(args...);
}
```

Which means that the expression where `return v + sum(args...)` becomes *discarded*
for when `sizeof...(Args) == 0` (called with one argument), instead of creating an error at instantiation time.

Comment: Andreas, interesting input. What about **C++ 20**, `concepts`?

Comment: @AlixBlaine Concepts are indeed interesting - I can recommend searching for it on the site.

Comment: **Andreas DM**, any examples with Concepts with the regard to this?

Answer (score 0):

For the simple example of adding some values, there will be most probably no difference using an optimizing compiler. The produced assembler code will be the same.

You may check this with "compiler explorer".

For your first solution with fold expressions, there a 4 possible implementations, which will all result in the same output. There is basically no difference.

Fold expressions have been introduced with C++17.

Before that people were using templates with specialization and recursive calls. This was very difficult to understand for many people.

Nowadays, using fold expressions, leads to simpler examples for simple binary operators. There are also very complex constructs with the comma operator and variadic / templatized lambdas. But anyway.

As C++ evolves, there are more, sometimes simpler solutions. And maybe there is a use case that would require to use the on or the other solution.

So, the answer to you second question could be: Evolution.

As for what to use, IMHO you should use fold expressions for your example.